# My async function is not waiting for a promise from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I am currently learning how async works, while working on a small project using Firebase databases. 
As far as I understand await should pause the function until a promise is resolved, but in my case it's not waiting for that.

I've shortened 2 functions I used to try and test this:

```
async findUser(id) {
        await this.firebase.findUserData(id).then(
            value => {
                console.log('finduser stopped waiting');
                return value;
            }
        )
    }
```

```
async findUserData(userId){
        console.log('firebase started looking for user');
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
            let user = (snapshot.val());
            console.log('found: ' + user);
            return user;
        });
    }
```

The console output looks like this:
[(not allowed to embed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvudI.png)

It's running findUser first, followed by the Firebase call, but does not wait for that promise to complete before returning a value. Found user id prints last.

I'm sure I'm doing something really dumb here, but I couldn't figure it out for a while now and have nobody else to turn to.

Sorry if the question is poorly written. First time posting around here. Welcome any feedback!

Comment: I **strongly** recommend writing `async` code (or any code that works with `Promise<T>`) in TypeScript which helps detect coding errors like these. Angular and Firebase both support TypeScript (and in Angular it's required): https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

Comment: Thanks. I definitely will when I can. This time around it's an extension of a project I'm doing for my CS course so I didn't have much choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not mix `await` and `then`s. Then you also don't forget to await a promise (you never await / return the Promise returned by .once):

```
async findUserData(userId){
    console.log('firebase started looking for user');
    const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value');
    let user = (snapshot.val());
    console.log('found: ' + user);
    return user;
}

async findUser(id) {
    const value = await this.firebase.findUserData(id);
    console.log('finduser stopped waiting');
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Wow. This was super quick. Thank you! 
I don't exactly understand why the async/then don't mix well? 
Does await not wait for the 'then()' part and executes right after first part is done?

Comment: Yes exactly. But that's exactly what you forgot. You attached a then, but did not await. If you always await you don't forget that, also it is far easier to read

Comment: @JonasWilms It took me 2 days to solve this issue. Thanks a lot for your answer.